# Export registry in plain text format

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My object is to export the Windows registry in txt format using a batch file.

If I use either of the following two lines from a batch file:

```
REG EXPORT C:\t.txt "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software"
REGEDIT /E C:\t.txt "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software"
```

I get output similar to this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe]
```

I am surprised with the output of export using the REGEDIT GUI. If I select File->Export
and change the "Save as type" to "Text Files", I get output similar to this:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   1/5/2011 - 8:27 AM

Key Name:          HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   11/4/2010 - 12:01 PM
```

I think the second example shows the data in a more readable format. I want to achieve the same output using cmd or batch file.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I get identical output from REG and REGEDIT. Can you provide more detail about the difference you are seeing?

Comment: is their any way to send u the files. I'll send u both files. reg and regedit produce same output. i am compareing output of reg/regedit with export using gui.

Comment: I get the same out from the REGEDIT GUI export and `REGEDIT /E t.txt keyname`. Are you saying you get different output from REGEDIT using the GUI and `\E` option?

Comment: Ok, I just re-read what you said and realized you're changing the "Save As Type" to "Text file". I was just exporting to a .txt file, not changing the type. After changing the type, I see that you do get the output formatted differently. I'm not sure yet if there is a way to do it from a batch file.

Comment: If you have hex values that need decoding to text you can use regtotext http://regtotext.blogspot.com

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this

```
START /W REGEDIT /E file.txt %REG_PATH%
```

By default it saves files with the .reg file extension. But it's a text file which can be executed by regedit and make changes in registry.

If you think this is not readable enough, try *[Import/Export registry sections as XML](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/registryasxml.aspx)*.

Comment: output of START /W REGEDIT /E file.txt %REG_PATH% is same as regedit /e, my problam is still remains. and link also not opening. please help